# Frequent timeouts on inserting to specific tables

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Hi and thanks for reading 
I have the following problem:
I'm inserting from vbnet into a google cloud mysql, reading from a MSSQL (this is why I use both SqlCommand and MySqlCommand) in two different table: one is ok(could insert thousands of lines with no errors at all), the second one gives frequent timeouts (about 15%).
Vbnet Code used is the same, and tables are pretty equal.
I get timeouts sometimes, for a few minutes, then its ok again for a few seconds(insert dozens in a row), and then fails again.

Hope someone has  an idea ... I'm lost here !!!

errors received:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at UpdateWebBDD.UpdateMySQL.uploadResults()
```

This code gives timeouts:

```
Function uploadGames() As Double
    Dim lrd As SqlDataReader
    Dim cmdMS As New SqlCommand
    Dim tot As Double
    Dim cur As Double
    Dim ko As Double
    cmdMS.Connection = conMSSQL
    uploadGames = 0
    lrd = ReadTable("Games")
    tot = 0
    While (lrd.Read)
        tot = tot + 1
    End While
    lrd = ReadTable("Games")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    While lrd.Read
        Cur = Cur + 1
        Try
            cmd.Connection = conMySQL
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & Mainform.tb_db.Text & ".Games VALUES(@GameNR, @FileName,@gametime,@gametype,@scorered,@scoregreen,@scoremixed,@nbPlayer,@game40,@scorepurple,@sitecode)"
            cmd.Prepare()

            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameNR", lrd.GetValue(0))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", lrd.GetValue(1))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gametime", lrd.GetValue(2))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gametype", lrd.GetValue(3))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scorered", lrd.GetValue(4))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoregreen", lrd.GetValue(5))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoremixed", lrd.GetValue(6))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nbPlayer", lrd.GetValue(7))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@game40", lrd.GetValue(8))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scorepurple", lrd.GetValue(9))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitecode", Mainform.tb_Site.Text)


            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
                ko = ko + 1
                WriteError(1, "Error inserting Games: no rows inserted" & vbCrLf, 2001)
            Else
                cmdMS.CommandText = "Update [Games] set online = 1 where GameNR = @GameNR"
                cmdMS.Parameters.Clear()
                cmdMS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameNR", lrd.GetValue(0))
                cmdMS.ExecuteNonQuery()
                uploadGames = uploadGames + 1
            End If
```

nextp:

```
        Catch edw As Exception
            WriteError(1, "Error inserting Games: exception " & vbCrLf & edw.ToString, 2002)
        End Try
        updateMainForm(uploadGames, ko, cur, tot)
    End While
    lrd.Close()
    cmdMS.Dispose()
    updateMainForm(uploadResults, ko, cur, tot)
    cmd.Dispose()
End Function
```

This one never gives timeouts:

```
Function uploadResultsDetails() As Double
        Dim lrd As SqlDataReader
        Dim cmdMS As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim tot As Double
    Dim cur As Double
    Dim ko As Double
    cmdMS.Connection = conMSSQL
    uploadResultsDetails = 0
    lrd = ReadTable("ResultsDetails")
    tot = 0
    While (lrd.Read)
        tot = tot + 1
    End While
    lrd = ReadTable("ResultsDetails")
    While lrd.Read
        Cur = Cur + 1
        Try
            cmd.Connection = conMySQL
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & Mainform.tb_db.Text & ".ResultsDetails VALUES(@ResultDetailNR, @hitshot,@totalline,@team,@playernr,@resultnr,@front,@rear,@shoulder,@gun,@total,@sitecode)"
            cmd.Prepare()

            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultDetailNR", lrd.GetValue(0))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hitshot", lrd.GetValue(1))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalline", lrd.GetValue(2))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team", lrd.GetValue(3))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playernr", lrd.GetValue(4))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resultnr", lrd.GetValue(5))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@front", lrd.GetValue(6))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rear", lrd.GetValue(7))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shoulder", lrd.GetValue(8))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gun", lrd.GetValue(9))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", lrd.GetValue(10))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitecode", Mainform.tb_Site.Text)


            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
                ko = ko + 1
                WriteError(1, "Error inserting ResultsDetails: no rows inserted" & vbCrLf, 4001)
            Else
                cmdMS.CommandText = "Update [ResultsDetails] set online = 1 where ResultDetailNR = @ResultDetailNR"
                cmdMS.Parameters.Clear()
                cmdMS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultDetailNR", lrd.GetValue(0))
                cmdMS.ExecuteNonQuery()
                uploadResultsDetails = uploadResultsDetails + 1
            End If
```

nextp:

```
        Catch edw As Exception
            WriteError(1, "Error inserting ResultsDetails: exception " & vbCrLf & edw.ToString, 4002)
        End Try
        updateMainForm(uploadResultsDetails, ko, cur, tot)
    End While
    lrd.Close()
    cmdMS.Dispose()
    updateMainForm(uploadResults, ko, cur, tot)
    cmd.Dispose()
End Function
```

Table definitions (they are just an online backup of a MSSQL BDD, to be used with PHP, they have no indexes, no nothing)
this table gives timeout

```
drop table if exists  `games` ;
CREATE TABLE `Games`(
    `GameNR` bigint  NOT NULL,
    `FileName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `gametime` datetime NULL,
    `gametype` nchar(10) NULL,
    `scorered` double NULL,
    `scoregreen` double NULL,
    `scoremixed` double NULL,
    `nbPlayer` double NULL,
    `game40` tinyint NULL,
    `scorepurple` double NULL,
    `SiteCode` nchar(4) NULL
)
;
```

this on does not:

```
drop table if exists  `ResultsDetails` ;
CREATE TABLE `ResultsDetails`(
    `ResultDetailNR` bigint NOT NULL,
    `hitshot` tinyint NOT NULL,
    `totalline` tinyint NOT NULL,
    `team` varchar(1) NULL,
    `playernr` bigint NULL,
    `resultnr` bigint NOT NULL,
    `front` nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `rear` nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `shoulder` nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `gun` nchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `total` nchar(4) NOT NULL,
    `SiteCode` nchar(4) NULL
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use System.Data.SqlClient when you insert/read data into/from a MySQL database ? 
It's probably looking for a Microsoft-SQL-Server where there is a MySQL server, then finds none, and waits for the timeout...

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   UpdateWebBDD.UpdateMySQL.uploadResults()

As far as I know, MySql commands are in the namespace `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry:
I just saw that it is the MSSQL server giving an error, not the MySQL !!
so the problem must be on my side. Even thought I still don't get why it gives a timeout ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was on MSSQL side
apparently it does not like to read a record and modify it.

the line cmdMS.CommandText = "Update [ResultsDetails] set online = 1 where ResultDetailNR = @ResultDetailNR" uses the same row than the one being read by the loop

I put it out of the loop, and it works like a charm ... strange but its ok to me. sorry for inconvenience.